# C#: How to create a folder for a specific function?

Tags: c#, selenium, screenshot

I am using Selenium for automation purpose. I have a class for screenshot and Page Object method to call all my element in different class for every page. Now I am calling get screenshot of page in every class. But here is the think how to do I create a folder name get the screenshot in that folder.

Result.cs

```
class Result
{       
        static int i = 1;

        public static void screenshot()
        {
            ITakesScreenshot screenshotDriver = myCollection.driver as ITakesScreenshot;
            Screenshot screenCapture = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
            string path = @"..\..\..\Results\ScreenShots\";
            string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss");

            {
                screenCapture.SaveAsFile(@path + i + timestamp + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                i++;
            }


        }
    }
```

LoginPageObject.cs

```
     [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "txtusername")]
     public IWebElement userName { get; set;}
     [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "Password")]
     public IWebElement pwd { get; set; }
     [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "login_button")]

public void Login(string uname, string paswd)
{
       userName.EnterText(uname);
       pwd.EnterText(paswd);
       clickLogin.Click();
       Result.screenshot();
       Thread.Sleep(4000);
}
```

Same for HomePageObject

main.cs

```
[Test]
public void Initialize()
{
    myCollection.driver = new TWebDriver();
    LoginPageObject objLogin = new LoginPageObject();

    string pathfile = @"..\..\a.xlsx";
    string sheetName = "Common";

    var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathfile);
    var abc = from a in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName)  select a;

    foreach (var a in abc)
    {
        myCollection.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(a["URL"]);
    }

    myCollection.driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

    foreach (var a in abc)
    {
        objLogin.Login(a["uname"], a["paswd"]);
    }

    HomePagePbject objHome = new HomePageObject();
    objHome.HomeFunction();
}
```

Here my main function is Initialize. So now how would I add all screenshots to that folder. For Now, I am adding it to screenshot folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like it: Create a folter to Logs and after append a screenshot folder inside it. If the folder does not exist, create it.

Using NUnit (but you can do the same with a similar sintax in VisualStudio.TestTools):

```
public void SaveScreenShot(string screenshotFirstName)
{
    var folderLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogPath"] +"\\ScreenShot\\";

    if (!Directory.Exists(folderLocation))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderLocation);

    var screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot) _driver).GetScreenshot();
    var image = ScreenshotToImage(screenshot);
    var filename = new StringBuilder(folderLocation);
    filename.Append(screenshotFirstName);
    filename.Append(".png");
    image.Save(filename.ToString(), ImageFormat.Png);
}

private static Image ScreenshotToImage(Screenshot screenshot)
{
    Image screenshotImage;
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(screenshot.AsByteArray))
    {
        screenshotImage = Image.FromStream(memStream);
    }
    return screenshotImage;
}

[TearDown]
public static void Cleanup()
{
    Browser.Dispose();
    var dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
    var data = dateTimeNow.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    IntegrationTest.WriteInLog("Test ends at: " + data);
    IntegrationTest.WriteInLog("Time to execute: " + (dateTimeNow - InicioTeste).TotalSeconds + " seconds");

    var takeScreenShoot = false;

    if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Equals(ResultState.Failure))
    {
        IntegrationTest.WriteInLog("FAILS");
        takeScreenShoot = true;
    }
    else if(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Equals(ResultState.Error))
    {
        IntegrationTest.WriteInLog("ERROR");
        takeScreenShoot = true;
    }
    else if(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Equals(ResultState.SetUpError))
    {
        IntegrationTest.WriteInLog("SETUP ERROR");
        takeScreenShoot = true;
    }
    else if(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Equals(ResultState.SetUpFailure))
    {
        IntegrationTest.WriteInLog("SETUP FAILURE");
        takeScreenShoot = true;
    }
    else if(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Equals(ResultState.Inconclusive))
    {
        IntegrationTest.WriteInLog("INCONCLUSIVE");
    }
    else if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Equals(ResultState.Success))
    {
        IntegrationTest.WriteInLog("SUCESS");
    }
    else
    {
        IntegrationTest.WriteInLog("UNKNOW");
    }

    if (takeScreenShoot)
    {
        Browser.SaveScreenShot(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name.ToUpper()));
        IntegrationTest.WriteInLog("Screenshot saved as " + TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name.ToUpper()));
    }

    IntegrationTest.WriteInLog("\n");
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't get what I am trying to do. Suppose in my main class I have three test case function Initialize, Send_Data, Search_Engine.

Comment: For each class calls my testcase steps, from that class I am getting screenshot. Now screenshot class is different. How to detect that that screenshot should go to particular folder as per my test case fuunction

Comment: So you can set the foldername as the testcase method name. You can get it using the TestContext and you can do it in a teardown method without call it explicity inside any method, at the end of testcase. I usually only save the screenshot if the method returns some error.

Comment: Not exactly. Also I didn't understood what are you doing from `if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Equals(ResultState.Failure))` to `IntegrationTest.WriteInLog("Screenshot saved as " + TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name.ToUpper()));`

Comment: A TearDown method is called after your testcase ends or fails. And, inside the class TestContext you can get some informations about the last running test method, like him name, if it runs with success or fails. So, you can create a folder to each test using this class, only using him name in a parameter.